# Add Partial Control dynamically in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to keep in the database the list of the "Modules" which are in fact Partial Views of the ASP .NET MVC.

Is it possible to define that dynamically?

**HTML**

```
<p>A Partial Control</p>

@Html.Partial("UserControls/ColorBlockUserControl", new ColorModel())

<hr />

<p>A Partial Control that is initialized on Server-Side</p>
@{
    Html.RenderAction("InitializeUserControl");
}
```

**C#**

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        { 
             return View(new HomeModel());
        }

        public ActionResult InitializeUserControl()
        {
            ColorModel colorModel = new ColorModel
            {
                Width = 200,
                Height = 200,
                RGBColor = "#FF0000"
            };

            return PartialView("UserControls/ColorBlockUserControl", colorModel);
        }
    }
```

I assume to use ViewBag to use like

```
 @ViewBag.InitializeUserControl = "InitializeUserControl"; // It goes from the database and can be ANY name


 Html.RenderAction(@ViewBag.InitializeUserControl);
```

***But it is not working...***

I hope u got the idea to define it

```
 Html.RenderAction("I need here the dynamic var");
```

Thanks!

***P.S. To make it clear the final idea is provide to the user editable template (CKEditor) so user can add any ASP .NET MVC UserControl name i.e. "Gadget1" or "Gadget2" and we are able dynamically change WebPage and show all controls  which have been added dynamically.***

Comment: @Anon Yeah... There are some errors... `CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MVCColorUserControl.Models.HomeModel>' has no applicable method named 'RenderAction' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.`

Comment: Any reason why it must be a partial view and not simply retrieved by Ajax?

Comment: Well, in your description you say they are partial views, but in the view your using: Html.RenderAction...Have you tried Html.Partial(@ViewBag.InitializeUserControl)?

Comment: @Anon Well. I did it. It doesnt work like u 've assumed. `CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MVCColorUserControl.Models.HomeModel>' has no applicable method named 'Partial' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
`

Comment: Do you have any @using statements in your view?

Comment: @Anon Yes.  `@model MVCColorUserControl.Models.ColorModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DrawColor", "ColorBlockUserControl", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "color-" + Model.Id }))
{`

Comment: Im sorry, i mean referenced using statements at the top: Like @using Microsoft.Web.Optimization

Comment: @gabriel I'd like to use Partial Views. But if you assume that Ajax is a good  option then please put your answer with a code sample. Thanks!

Comment: I just sow the @satpal answer to use to do like `Html.RenderAction((string)@ViewBag.InitializeUserControl);`  and it is working! yeah!!! Put your answer again SATPAL!

Comment: After reading your updated note at the end Ajax wont actually work as you are planning to use mvc controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @satpal

He put his answer and after that deleted it. I don't know why. But he is right!

```
Html.RenderAction((string)@ViewBag.InitializeUserControl);
```

This is working!